# How to animate two view using Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i need to develop sample animations application using objectiveC.

i have two buttons on two different UiView's. one view contain profile button and another view contain setting button, when click on profile button view will increase its width and height automatically settings button view also change place. and vice versa.

please find below images[image]

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Try to make use of sectioned table view

Comment: thank you Bhargavi, can we done using UIView or not

Comment: You can. Totally depends on you which control you want to use

Comment: adding two view's for self.view

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want here is a collapsible UITableView, apple has a great example here:

[Table view updates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

Otherwise all you need to do is modify the frame inside the method in this block like this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    myView.frame = newFrame
                }];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

when the down button is pressed for profile view, then do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [profileView setFrame:CGRectMake(profileView.frame.origin.x, profileView.frame.origin.y, profile.frame.size.width, finalHeight)];
        [settingsView setFrame:CGRectOffset(settingsView.frame, 0, final_Y_Coordinate)];

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
```

So what this basically, do is, it increases the height of profile view and simultaneously change Y-Coordinate of Settings View.

You can do same thing for settingsView where only height of settingsView changes.

Hope it helps!